# Make the input wait for mouse or keyboard - Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, input, keyboard, mouse, simultaneous

I fixed my program, but now the loop seems to be stuck. Whenever I press <kbd>u</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd>, it is stuck, but the mouse part works :)

```
; You may customize this and other start-up templates; 
; The location of this template is c:\emu8086\inc\0_com_template.txt

org 100h

CLEAR   MACRO
    MOV AX,0600H
    MOV BH,07
    MOV CX,0000
    MOV DX,184FH
    INT 10H
  ENDM  

CURSOR  MACRO Col, Row
    MOV AH,02
    MOV BH,00
    MOV DL,Col
    MOV DH,Row
    INT 10H
  ENDM

DISP   MACRO MES
    MOV AH,09
    MOV DX,OFFSET MES
    INT 21H
ENDM

CLEARLINE MACRO ROW
    CURSOR 00,ROW
    DISP SPACES

ENDM





.MODEL SMALL ; RUN THE PROGRAM IN DIMENSIONS 79x24 
.STACK 64H
.DATA

OPTION1         DB      '1. Press "U" to Speed up the motor','$'
OPTION2         DB      '2. Press "D" to Slow Down the motor','$'
OPTION3         DB      '1. Right click the mouse to turn motor direction to clockwise','$'
OPTION4         DB      '2. Left click the mouse to turn the motor direction to anti-clockwise','$'
SPEEDUP         DB      'DC motor is speeding up ','$'
SLOWDOWN        DB      'DC motor is slowing down','$'
RIGHT           DB      'DC motor will now rotate clockwise','$'
LEFT            DB      'DC motor will now rotate anti-clockwise','$'
SPACES          DB      '                                                                                    ','$'





.CODE
MAIN:   MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS, AX
        CLEAR
        CURSOR 24,9
        DISP OPTION1
        CURSOR 24,10
        DISP OPTION2
        CURSOR 14,13
        DISP OPTION3
        CURSOR 8,14
        DISP OPTION4
L0:     MOV AH, 01H
        INT 16h
        JZ MOUSETIME
        JNZ COMPARE

COMPARE: CMP AL,'U'
        JE FASTER
        CMP AL,'u'
        JE FASTER
        CMP AL,'D'
        JE SLOWER
        CMP AL,'d'
        JE SLOWER

MOUSETIME:  MOV AX,03
        INT 33H
        CMP BX,0
        JZ L0
        JNZ SKIP
SKIP:   CMP BX,1    ;MOUSE LEFT
        JE MRIGHT
        CMP BX,2    ;MOUSE RIGHT
        JE MLEFT

FASTER: CLEARLINE 19
        CURSOR 27,19
        DISP SPEEDUP
        JMP L0

SLOWER: CLEARLINE 19
        CURSOR 27,19
        DISP SLOWDOWN
        JMP L0

MRIGHT: CLEARLINE 19
        CURSOR 18,19
        DISP RIGHT
        JMP L0

MLEFT:  CLEARLINE 19
        CURSOR 18,19
        DISP LEFT
        JMP L0

        MOV AH, 4CH
        INT 21H
    END MAIN

ret
```

Any tips on fixing this? I tried a lot of things but it doesn't seem to work. I will try more things, but any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your advice knm241. 
The above program now works fine thanks to you. The only problem that occurred was that the keyboard buffer was not clearing and thus the program would get stuck in a loop. I fixed that by clearing the buffer and now everything works.

I used this macro to clear the buffer.

```
BUFFER MACRO
    MOV AH,0C 
    MOV AL,0 
    INT 21H 
    ENDM
```

and added it to FASTER and SLOWER jumps before it jumped back into the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this interrupt service? [INT16/AH=01h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm)

You can use it this way

```
mov ah, 01h
int 16h
jz _no_keyboard_input_present
jnz _keyboard_input_present
```